# Call mainWindow methtod from the page into a frame

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a main window with combobox data. Within the window I have a frame with a page, I need to refresh the data in the combobox (I have a method to do this)
How do I call the method from the page?

in my MainWindow

```
    public  void getCustomers()
    {
        cb_Name.ItemsSource = ve.Folders;
        cb_Name.DisplayMemberPath = "Full_Name";
        cb_Name.SelectedValuePath = "Folder_Id";
        cb_Name.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

in my page

```
    private void btn_insert_person_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

     }
```

Maybe now more clearly

Comment: Is the refresh method part of the mainWindow?

Comment: How do you create the "page" from the "MainWindow"? Some more code would be helpful

Comment: private void btn_New_Customer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            My_Frame.Content = new Open_Folder();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a method like in your main window class:

```
public void RefreshComboBox();
```

When you're creating the new frame you can pass a "method pointer" to it.

Let's pretend you're currently initializing the frame like this:

```
var frame = new Frame();
```

You can change its constructor to this:

```
public Frame(Action refreshComboBox)
```

and initialize the frame like this:

```
var frame = new Frame(RefreshComboBox);
```

Save a reference to the "method pointer" in your Frame class and call it when needed.

More info about the Action delegate here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Comment: One. Thank you very much 2. I did not understand the answer, but it seems very clear (I'm updated the question with code)